# bind is not a member of std

Tags: c++

I am using netbeans 7.2.1 with minwg compiler. I am getting the following error messages when trying to build the application:

> error: 'function' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
>
> error: 'bind' is not a member of 'std'

although I included functional.h in the begining of the file, and I am using 'function' and 'bind' in the form of: std::function and std::bind

Where is the problem? Is it in the compiler or there is something missing? I remember that I compiled and ran the same application successfully on visual studio 2010.

Comment: None of the standard C++ headers end in .h (if you don't count the C compatibility ones).

Answer (score 18):

It is not `functional.h`, it is  just `functional`.

```
#include <functional> //without .h
```

Note that `std::function` and `std::bind` come with C++11 only. So you might have to upgrade your compiler in case you have not done yet.

Also, compile your code with `-std=c++11` option:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp
```

That should work if you've upgraded your compiler. If your compiler is a bit old, you can also try `-std=c++0x` instead.

Comment: I included the functional.h header. I am using mingw-get 0.5-beta-2012-04026-1 but not sure whether it supports c++11

Comment: I read it of course and I know it's functional with no .h! However, I am not sure whether mingw that I'm using supports c++11, considering that I just downloaded it today from sourceforge website!

Comment: @user1638717: Alright. I edited my answer again. You need to use `--std=c++11` option.

Comment: Thanks for the great help. However, I'm using netbeans 7.2.1 IDE and not compiling from the command line; is it possible to guide me to add this compilation option through netbeans IDE, or something making it working like this option of commandline? Thank you again.

Comment: @user1638717: I'm sure netbeans has some settings where you can set this option. Just explore it. Starts with settings, tools, compiler-options, or compilation, anything that sounds reasonable enough to you.

Comment: The correct spelling of the option is `-std` not `--std` and for compatibility with GCC 4.3 to 4.6 it's necessary to use `-std=c++0x` not `-std=c++11`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Both works! I sometime write `-std=c++11`, sometime `--std=c++11`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try to find how to work it up in netbeans IDE!

Answer (score 6):

You need to include the header `functional`. It is available in [C++11](http://oopscenities.net/2012/02/24/c11-stdfunction-and-stdbind/). If you are still having problems, then your compiler may not support C++11 yet. Try upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use boost::bind:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
```